# create reinit function for a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ to let user add tags but I cannot make it working for the future element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aydoywLq/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input data-role="tagsinput" type="text" />
</div>

<button>add row</button>

$('button').click(function() {
    $('.wrapper').append($('input').clone());
});
```

Since the plugin doesn't have a `reinit` function, perhaps I have to create one? Where to begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.tagsinput()` constructor for creating a new tagsinput element manually.

```
$(item).tagsinput();
```

I have changed your code a little so that it creates an empty object because `clone()` copied entered values as well.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aydoywLq/1/).